# Reset ASMB8 BMC Credentials

Tags: ipmi, password-reset, bmc

I just got a server from a client and I need to reset the BMC credentials.

I have an external KVM connected, I can access the BIOS and set the network address for the BMC, but I can't find a place to reset the credentials.

I also have access to the machine operating system (windows).

What should I do to reset the BMC credentials?

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

since you have an OS loaded with network connectivity (Windows it looks to be) there is another method using IPMICFG from SuperMicro:

You need to download IPMICFG for Windows from here: https://www.supermicro.com/SwDownload/SwSelect_Free.aspx?cat=IPMI You have to "Accept EULA" and then Download. It may also ask you for your name and email prior to showing the download links.

Once that's extracted you can open a command prompt in admin mode and navigate to the correct folder similar to this:

C:\Users\YOURUSER\Desktop\IPMICFG_1.32.0_build.200910\Windows\64bit
Then you can run the following commands in the command prompt:

ipmicfg-win.exe -user list (Just to verify the users you want exist)
ipmicfg-win.exe -user setpwd 2 your_password_here
Let me know if that doesn't work for you - hopefully it will assist with not having to constantly reboot.

Answer (score 2):

Admin mode Command prompt execution of IPMIConfig should work for any recent server as @Thayron Arrais describes and it should be your first choice.

On X8/H8 Generation and older hardware it may not always succeed. In those cases, if you reflash the IPMI Firmware with the -C (clear config) option on the flash utility, even with the same version currently on the device, from an admin command prompt you can reset the IPMI configuration to its default settings.

On the older Systems that is ADMIN/ADMIN (in all CAPS). On systems produced after a California law on default passwords went into place, that password is printed on a labels attached to the Chassis Toe Tag, or the motherboard directly.

This method also works for clearing BIOS System and User passwords using the regular Firmware flash utility -- physical access is godmode as far as permissions go.

The BIOS lets you set an IP, once it is set, you are expected to do everything through the redfish webgui or various OS provided IPMI/i2C tools. If your system supports it I highly recommend enabling the dedicated remote management interface if your system has one. Don't use the failover interface mode for security reasons.